Where to place the PCIe slot on a mini-ITX board?
I'm designing a mini-ITX board and it's surprisingly hard to find any info on where the PCIe slot is located.
The mini-ITX spec that I found contains the board and screw dimensions but refers to the micro-ATX specification for PCIe location.

And then mini-ATX specification is a big jumble of dimensions with a different datum and convoluted offsets between ISA, AGP, and PCI connectors.

If I do the math, I come out to
>>> -1.2-1.8+0.812+0.8*3
0.212

in inches from datum C to pin 1 of the PCI slot.
But if you look at how their PCI slot is staggered it's different from mine:

I could take the horizontal position of A2 and the vertical position of A1, in essence virtually staggering them the other way.
But my confidence level of correctly placing the slot is pretty low by now.

is 0.212" from datum C correct?
where is "pin 1" on my footprint?
is my footprint even correct? (part)


Doesn't it have to be in the same place as for an ATX board so as to fit with the same slot locations in a case? (Maybe a backwards inference.)

The question seems to mix PCI and PCIe slots, which use different connectors. Can the question be clarified?

Because I hadn't seen a PCI card in decades so I forgot it's a completely different socket

From this Silverstone Tech Talk page, it gives various diagrams, including the Mini-ITX one you show.
Amongst them is a diagram for Mini-DTX, which uses the same mounting holes for Mini-ITX, it's just wider to accommodate two expansion cards.

This gives the necessary location for the PCIe connector datum position for the first slot. The centre-line of the slot is -0.738" + 0.8" = 0.062" (1.57mm) towards the I/O region from the datum mount hole.
The centre of the PCIe connector notch which is where the connector datum lies, is located 1.848" (46.94mm) inwards from the datum mount hole.
Both of these measurements match the PCIe CEM Specification.

The relationship of PCIe connector pins to the connector datum is shown in the following connector footprint. Apologies for the change in units, the values shown in the footprint image are millimetres. The datam is the 2.35mm drill.


"Apologies for the change in units" kinda inevitable when standards from different eras meet.

I think your math is correct for a PCI slot in the first position, relative to datum C.

-1.8 for datum c to datum b.
-1.2 for datum c to pin 1 of an isa slot in position 4
0.812 for isa to PCI in the same slot position (the spec was designed so PCI and ISA could share a slot position, hence the large offset)


0.8 * 3 because we want slot position 1, not 4.



The problem is you don't want a PCI slot, you want a PCIe slot. Neither the Atx, nor the mini-itx specifications seem to tell you where to put PCIe slots.
I suspect the information needed to correctly locate a PCIe slot can be found in the PCIe specifications somewhere, but those are unfortunately rather expensive to obtain legitimately.
Another possible information source is to look at other ATX derived form factors. SSI EEB is a much more recent spec, intended for dual socket server boards, which is based on ATX but with a larger PCB and extra mounting holes. Being a much more recent spec it has locations for PCIe slots.
https://www.snia.org/sites/default/files/SSIF/2018-05-31/SSI%20EEB%202011%201.0.1.pdf
(note: horizontal and vertical in the description below refer to the orientation of the board in the diagram, with the expansion slots and IO plate at the top).
According to the diagram in that spec, a PCIe slot in the 7th position has pin 1 0.211 inches horizontally and 1.389 inches vertically from datum A.
Datum A to datum C is 4.9 inches horizontally (and the same position vertically). So we have -4.9 + 0.8*6 + 0.211 = 0.111 inches horizontally from datum C to pin 1 of your slot.
